# Got Hat Trick, but haven't hit rep cap

Tags: support, winter-bash-2015

The description for Hat Trick is:

> hit the reputation cap on three different days

I just earned this hat, but this is my reputation today so far. Note that I have two accepted answers, so I didn't actually hit the rep cap. I hope to actually earn the cap, but I haven't quite gotten there yet:

[image]

Comment: Hey, wait, don't tell them yet.

Comment: I thought that accepted answers did count... it was only bounties that don't count?

Comment: @Catija Nope, neither count. If they did count, I'd only be at +200 :)

Comment: I guess it’s the same algorithm as for determining the Mortarboard/Epic/Legendary badges, which also just goes by the total amount of reputation.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Yeah, but those just say "Earn 200 daily reputation"

Comment: @Barry: Mortarboard also says that this is the daily maximum, which is equally wrong or misleading.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Could fix that one too while we're at it :)

Comment: @balpha I believe this question "indicates a reproducible problem on the site that you believe is due to a mistake, malfunction, or programming error," rather than being "[a] request for assistance with one of the site's features." Why did you retag it?

Answer (score 9):

Mortarboard (etc) also count when you reach 200, even if acceptances (or bounties!) could bring you higher.  From your experience it seems that the hat follows the same rules as for awarding these badges -- which makes sense, as that allows them to use code that's already there.  Why invent *another* potentially-confusing algorithm when the one that's in place will do the job?

Comment: I don't have issue with the algorithm: hitting 200+ on 3 days seems perfectly fine. But the text on the hat doesn't say hitting 200, it says hitting the rep cap. The wording should reflect what it actually does.

Comment: Oh, it looked like the bug you were reporting was the calculation, not the wording.

Comment: Well it's either a calculation bug or a wording bug.